# How to like a track and view all liked tracks on my Like index page in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, social-likes

I am building a music streaming app and am busy with Likes functionality. The flow is that a user sees a list of tracks and then likes a track. Then, the user navigates to a Likes page where they can see all of the tracks they liked.

When the user clicks the "heart" icon, I am attempting to use **simple_form** which has two hidden fields. One field is populated with **track.id** , the other field should take a **@likes.id**. However, as the user is not supposed to create a "Likes Playlist", I do not have a likes_id available.

As expected, the error that comes up when navigating to likes page is **Couldn't find Like without an ID**

**Question:** Can anyone clarify how I might create a likes_id without having to create one in new.html.erb?

**Side note: the user can currently create multiple playlist and can add songs to the chosen playlist, I tried following that same logic for Likes so apologies if I am way off.**

Here is my routes

```
resources :likes do
  resources :tracks
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :playlists
  has_many :tracks
  has_many :albums
  has_many :likes
  has_one_attached :photo
end
```

Likes model

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :liked_tracks
    has_many :tracks, through: :liked_tracks 
    belongs_to :user
    has_one_attached :photo
end
```

Here is my join table between tracks and likes

```
class LikedTrack < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :like
    belongs_to :track
end
```

My tracks Model

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :album
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :playlist_tracks
    has_many :playlists, through: :playlist_tracks
    has_many :likes, through: :liked_tracks
    has_many :tags, through: :tags_tracks
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :playlist_tracks, allow_destroy: true

    validates :title, presence: true, length: { in: 1..20 }
    validates :description, presence: true, length: { in: 10..60 }
    has_one_attached :photo
    has_one_attached :track
end
```

Here is my Likes Controller

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @tracks = LikedTrack.all
    end
    
    def show
        @liked = Like.find(params[:id])
        @tracks = @liked.tracks
    end

    def new
        @liked = Like.new
    end

    def create
        @liked = Like.new(track_params)
        @liked.user = current_user
        if @liked.save!
            redirect_to likes_path(@liked)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private

    def track_params
        params.require(:liked_track).permit(:track_id, :like_id)
    end


end
```

Here is my LikedTracks controller

```
class LikedTracksController < ApplicationController

    def new
    @liked = Like.new
    end

    def create
    @liked_track = LikedTrack.new(liked_track_params)
        if @liked_track.save!
            redirect_to station_index_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private

    def liked_track_params
        params.require(:liked_track).permit(:track_id, :like_id)
    end

end
```

This is my navigation to likes page

```
    <div class="flex">
    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
    <%= link_to "Liked", likes_path(current_user), class: "nav-text" %>
    </div>
```

This is the form embedded within each track card

```
<%= simple_form_for @liked_track, url: liked_tracks_path, method: :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :like_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: DESIRED @likes.id} %>
    <%= f.input :track_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: track.id } %>
    <%= button_tag type: 'submit', class: "like-button", id: "like-button" do %>
        <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
<% end %>
```

Tracks should render on the index page of Likes (index.html.erb).

Thanks and hope my provided code isn't an overkill. Let me know if you need an update to this post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your logic is a bit weird here, you can simplify everything with the following:

1. Drop the `Like` model and database table (not sure why do you want to attach a photo here?)
2. Change the `LikedTrack` to belong to `User` instead of `Like`
3. Rename the `LikedTrack` to `Like`

Now you only need to create a new Like record when user clicks the "heart" button, it should take the `track_id` and `user_id` as arguments behind your form.

Comment: Thanks guys, am busy with your recommendations and will relay back when I am done.

Comment: So I am not completely solved but you were right to simply my models and controllers. Also nested likes inside of tracks in my routes and have been following this tutorial a bit closer : https://medium.com/full-taxx/how-to-add-likes-to-posts-in-rails-e81430101bc2